# How to make a default woocommerce product title?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

What I want to have is that every new product will have the default title like this: shoe  Size 10
Because there will be add many products everyday it would be much easier to have that as a default product title. Does someone have a code for this or can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Secondary title plugin". Instructions on link below [secondary title plugin](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/secondary-title/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This Method

```
add_product( 'the_title', 'product_title');
function product_title( $title, $id ) {
if ( is_shop() && get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' ) {
return ( $title); 
} else {
return $title;
}
}
```

Comment: The page you want to show the title of the product.

Comment: I think you got my question wrong. What I mean is that when I add a new product I want to have already a default title filled in instead of filling it in by myself.

Comment: You have question what you asked  "How to make a default woocommerce product title?"

Comment: Ask your question in a wrong way, first clear what to ask